# Web: pan, rotate, and zoom image viewer - javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, image, rotation, zooming, pan

I saw a product viewer in [this website](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/mobile-phones/p9/images/p9/p9-viewer/index.html), and I'm trying to know how to implement this type of image viewer.

I just need to know if there's a specific name for this technique and I'll do further researching. I've tried searching for pan, rotate, zoom, and 360 image viewer but I can't find a more similar example.
They all spin in one direction.

Comment: they are using canvas